# PIP3 installation always tried to fetch packages from git-lfs directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pip, git-lfs

Every time I try to install a package using pip3 it is trying to fetch the package from the git-lfs package repository, which of course returns an HTTP 404 error.

I have already tried uninstalling and installing pip3. For example when trying to install bokeh:

```
pip3 install --default-timeout=1000 bokeh
```

I obtain the exception:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/pypi/simple/bokeh/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install from [jupyter's website](https://jupyter.org/install).

See these two Solutions one for Virtual and second is for non virtual:/

Steps: 
Step 1. Install the notebook using `pip3 install jupyter`
Step 2. Install bokeh using `pip3 install bokeh`
Step 3. Start the notebook using jupyter notebook
(In the last step do the process without activating virtual environment)

Run in virtual environment:
Step 1. Activate your virtual environment
Step 2. Install the notebook using `python -m pip install jupyter`
Step 3. Install bokeh using `python -m pip install bokeh`
Step 4. Start the notebook using jupyter notebook

Comment: I cannot install anything with pip

Comment: See i have posted new answer where i got the same challenge, this is just a tricky proxy settings.